# C++ operator overloading for wrapper class

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, wrapper

I'm using a class called Pointer, which is some kind of a wrapper around a real pointer I guess. I think this line of code in this class enables me to get the real pointer:

```
 operator const T* () const;
```

What does this mean exactly? How can I call this?

Suppose `myPointer` is a `Pointer<int16_t>` object. I should be able to get the `int_16*` object which wraps this pointer, by using the operator overloading above, but I don't know how.

**Edit**

Based on the answers belo, I now know I can do this:

```
const int16_t* myRealPointer = myPointer;
```

Now suppose I need to call a function which expects a `int16_t*` parameter (so without the const). What can I do to pass this myRealPointer object to that function?

Comment: The keywords you are looking for are "implicit conversion operators"; you can trigger it by casting `myPointer` to `int_16*` (assuming there's also a non-const version of that operator), by assigning it to an object of type `int_16*`, by passing it to a function that expects an object of type `int_16*` and in some other circumstances I don't remember. In practice, an implicit conversion operator enables the object to decay to the target type at the tiniest hint you may need such conversion.

Comment: maybe the question title is misleading, also the tags

Comment: @Wolf don't hesitate to adjust it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a conversion operator. For example, you could use it to convert a `Pointer<T>` to a *real* `T*` and, additionally, use it everywhere a `T*` is expected:

```
Pointer<float> p(new float);
const float* p2 = p;
```

In this case, the operator is only defined for the conversion to const raw pointers, so `float* p2 = p;` would not work. (Also there might be a similar operator for that case.)

Comment: The only true answer.

Comment: Thanks. Now suppose I need to call a function which expects a int16_t* parameter, and I have a const int16_t* object. What can I do to pass this object to that function?

Comment: @Fortega declare an int16_t variable and pass the address of it to the function call, another option is casting the const away, but this could be dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

This is not `operator ()` as you wrote in the title of the question. It is an implicit conversion operator that converts an object of type `Pointer<T>`to an object of type `T *`. So everywhere where an object of type `T *` is expected you may use an object of type `Pointer<T>`.

For example

```
Pointer<int16_t> myPointer;

/* initialization of myPointer */

if ( myPointer != NULL ) std::cout << myPointer << std::endl;
```

In this code snippet the operator is called twice: in the if condition and in the output statement.

If you do not want such an implicit conversion you could declare the operator with function specifier `explicit`. For example

```
explicit operator const T* () const;
```

If you want indeed to write `operator ()` that is named like the function call operator then it can look the following way

```
const T * operator ()() const;
```

In this case the above code snippet would look differently

```
Pointer<int16_t> myPointer;

/* initialization of myPointer */

if ( myPointer() != NULL ) std::cout << myPointer() << std::endl;
```